# What is LoadChildrenCallback

Tags: angular

What is LoadChildrenCallback interface in angular 2 and how can we use it?

I was going through the angular2 apis, so searched on internet as well but nothing  found.

Answer (score 0):

When you do lazyLoading with Router and lazy state is resolved this callback will be called.

official doc - https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback